# How to block pdf file in apache2 - Ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2, directory, pdf

I have a pdf file under my document root (/var/www/html) name is test.pdf. I want to restricted my pdf file if anyone try in browser like http://example.com/test.pdf, in this case i want pdf not view. I already try by htaccess and restricted that directory but failed.

Can anyone help me to provide any trust solution?

Comment: What did you try with htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code in to the to the apache httpd config:

```
<Files  ~ "\.pdf$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

This code will deny access to all the `*.pdf` files. But the question is why you keep in httpd docs directory files you do not want to expose to the world.

If you want to restrict access to only one file the code in config should be like:

```
<Files  test.pdf>
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: try but not working...
Under my directory lots of pdf file here...

Comment: @SomirRanjanPaul I have to agree with Romeo here, why keep it there?

Comment: @MichaelBay under my directory I have lots of pdf file, I want noone can view any by puting URL in web..

Comment: @SomirRanjanPaul Yes, I understand that and I think we all do but the question remains, why put them there in the first place if you don't want to expose them? And this script should work, upvoting.

Comment: Actually those file not in 1st place. Those file stored in few directory inner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to deny access to file types:

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder/.+\.(pdf|gif|js)$
```

This will return a 403 Access forbidden error for clients if they try to access `/folder/file.extension`

Comment: try but this is working ... anythings else

Comment: If working don't fix :)